# Add columns together for total value

Tags: php, mysql, database

I'm trying to add all the size columns from `id 1` together to get a total value.

The table looks a little bit like this:

```
-------------
| id | size |
-------------
| 1  | 6289 |
| 2  | 103  |
| 1  | 3719 |
| 3  | 8398 |
| 1  | 189  |
-------------
```

How would I add together all the `<b>size</b`> from`id <b>1</b` to get the total  value `(10197)` using php and mysql?

Comment: this is quite broad. [edit] to show your attempts

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: Well, rather than just letting us do the work for you (i.e. show you the answer), you should provide us with some info about where you are stuck in the process of solving the problem.

Please provide more context about what you've tried, what errors you are getting, etc. and you'll get much better responses to you questionn

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try this way

```
SELECT SUM(size) FROM your_table_name WHERE id=1
```

Comment: It seems to be doing well, this is adding them all together, right?

Comment: @ohpls, Yes the SUM() function returns the total sum of a numeric column,see http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_func_sum.asp

Comment: OP didn't ask this, but I felt I should add it as a comment. If you ever think you'll want to display totals for all ids, you can use this function with a group by clause: `SELECT id, SUM(size) AS total FROM myTable GROUP BY id;`

Answer (score -1):

MySQL provides a SUM() function that can be used to get the sum of any column in the records returned by query.
It can also be used with multiple columns. Provided they are used in an expression and expression is passed as a parameter to SUM function. Eg: SUM(col1*col2).

Since you are looking for sum of size with id = 1, below can be a solution as provided in above answer:

`SELECT SUM(size) FROM table_name WHERE id='1'`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Code only answers are often discouraged. I would recommend you edit this answer to give a little explanation of what your query is doing.